# change terminal directory using c language

Tags: c, linux, terminal

i am trying to change the directory of my linux terminal using c language. the thing is i am using threads. i have tried to use chdir() but its not working, n yes chdir() is also a process function.
 Actually the thing i am trying to implement is, i am trying to make a multi threaded program which compiles Linux kernel, and that is not possible without specifying directories( i have tried to do it without specifying directories but failed :) )

can anybody help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Giving some example code you're using might be helpful. My understanding is that by default the Linux Kernel configuration creates a Makefile which can then be made in parallel using `make -jN` with N make jobs. Assuming this isn't possible (for some reason, perhaps describe?) I would guess that a similar approach using relative paths could be used from some 'parent' build directory?

Comment: Why `chdir()` does not work?  Can you post more detail, such as errno when it fails or it does not change directory for you?

Comment: chdir() acts like nothing happended.. no error no directory change no nothing.. does nothing at all

Comment: @user2353613 It's not clear to me whether you want to change the directory of the terminal that launched your program (which is not possible) or whether you want to change current directory in a one (or more) threads?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202316). You mentioned something about trying to compile a kernel from a program; how about if you give us some more details on that, and how you're trying to do it?

Comment: To compile the Linux kernel in parallel, use the `-j` option to `make-kpkg` (or to `make`)

Comment: Blue Moon- i am not trying to change the directory of the terminal, i am trying to change the directory path in the terminal. e.g if i want to acces some file in the Download folder,in terminal i would simply type the command " cd Downloads/ " but if i want to do it with c code what should i do... i have tried chdir(Downloads/) but its not working.

Comment: @user2353613 So you want to change directories in the threads only?

Comment: yes,so that i can access the thing i want,( placed in that directory)

Answer (score 4):

You can't! No process can change the working directory of another. A process can only change its own WD. When you launch an external command such like your C program, then a new process is launched.
The `cd` command of your shell is an internal one.

Comment: there must be some way to chnge path using c :?

Comment: A thread is just a part of a process, and there is only one current directory per process. Changing the current directory in a thread changes the current directory of the whole process. This is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve. It appears that somehow you wish to emulate the behaviour of a script (or the `make` tool) using a C program, that is to say having the C program you wrote launch new processes (using `system` or perhaps a combination of `fork` and `exec*`). If that is the case, then what you actually want is to modify the environment variables of these processes for them to find the files they need. A forked process will inherit the environment of its parent, so all you need is to use `getenv`, `putenv`, `setenv` and `unsetenv` to retrieve and set the environment variables you want to add, update or remove; or you may use the specific `execve`, `execvpe` which let you specify exactly what environment should be available to the new program.

references:

- [fork system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)
- [exec family of system calls](http://linux.die.net/man/7/exec)
- [unix environment](http://linux.die.net/man/7/environ)